# adding zeros in objective-c string formats

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, nsstring, numbers

Quick question: I am trying to fill in empty spaces with a specific number of zeroes in an NSString stringWithFormat formatting string. 
For example, I want:

```
@"The number is %d", 5   // I want this to output 'the number is 05'
@"the number is %d", 10  // I want this to output 'the number is 10'
```

I know how to do this in Java, but I cant seem to find the same function in objective-c.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If in Java you use `System.out.printf()`, then it's the same format syntax in Objective-C (and C, for that matter):

```
NSLog(@"The number is %02d", 5);
NSLog(@"The number is %02d", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use something like:

```
char res[255];
sprintf(res, "the number is %02d", 5);
```